# PHP How to get userID (variable) in pop up modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

A number of employees and their info gets shown on a page. The info of employees gets retrieved via a DB and then a `foreach()` loop is used to display all employees who fit the search criteria, an example can be seen on image below

[image]

Now when the user clicks the button, a simple Bootstrap pop up modal gets triggered, with some basic form fields. As can be seen from example image below

[image]

**My Problem**

I need to get the `$userID` when a button is clicked to work with / process data in modal.

Below is an extract of relevant code:

```
$teacherClass = new TeacherSearch();
            $teachers = $teacherClass->showAllTeachers();
            if (is_array($teachers)) {
            foreach ($teachers as $teacher) {
                 $src = $teacher['userID'];
<div class="teacher-info">
                        <p class="teacherLabel">
                            NAME:
                            <?php
                            echo $teacher['name'];
                            ?>
                        </p>

                        <p class="teacherLabel">
                            HEADLINE:
                            <?php
                            echo $teacher['headline'];
                            ?>

                        <p class="teacherLabel">
                            LOCATION:
                            <?php
                            echo $teacher['location']
                            ?>
                        </p>
                       <!--BUTTON GOES HERE-->
                        }//foreach
```

**What I've tried**

Ive tried using an `<a>` element binding a parameter with userID to it, like so:

```
<a href="body.php?teacher='<?php echo $teacher['userID'] ?>'" data-target="#myModal">Hire <?php echo $teacher['name'] ?></a>
```

As is to be expected the following triggered a new page reload inside the modal.

I then tried using a # sign for `ahref` attribute and then biding parameter `$userID` to it like so:

```
 <a href="#?teacher='<?php echo $teacher['userID'] ?>'"></a>
```

The above lead to an undefined index error as can be seen in the picture above.

**Conclusion**

I hope this question makes sense, I'm pretty much out of ideas, no idea how to further approach this problem.

Comment: Why not just use data tags? Add data-id to the html element, then pass it with jquery/java script

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs thanks for that ill read up on `data-id `attribute never used it / heard of it.

Comment: no worries :) see @anand's answer for an example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the user-id in the anchor tag.To get the contents of the attribute data-id you have to use

```
<a id="myid" data-id="123">link</a>
<script>
  $('#myid').data("id");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript function to get `userID` and show `modal`:

```
<a  onclick="myfunction('<?php echo $userID; ?>')>Hire <?php echo $teacher['name'] ?></a>
```

javascript function:

```
var userID; // global
function myfunction(id){
    userID = id;
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
    //do somethings with user id here 
}
```